# Change the default location of inbuilt screen recorder

Tags: gnome, screencast

Ubuntu has an inbuilt screen recorder/screencast.

The default location it saves is `~/Videos`. But I want to change it to `~/Videos/Screenrecord` or something other than the default location. Can someone help me to do that.

I know it has been asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122784/how-can-i-change-the-default-save-location-the-gnome3-screencast), but it was marked unhelpful, which I think is wrong, as it has more than a few hundred views. So I would like to open it again.

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried `dconf editor`, but there is no option for this. Only option is to set max time limit of recording.

Comment: AFAIK it's hard-coded, there's no *easy* way to change it. It only allows to change the keybinding and the length.