# Screencast into a USB Stick

Tags: screencast

When looking at the screencast option, it said that it saves automatically to the Videos folder.  Is there a way to have it save directly onto a USB stick?

Comment: Just to be clear, which screencasting software are you using and which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am on 18.04, and plan to use the default screencasting (ctr alt shift r)

Comment: When you submitted your question, it informed you that you may not like the answer. So, I will link you to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254107/change-the-default-location-of-inbuilt-screen-recorder). Though that answer is dated, I don't believe circumstances have changed. The answer is that it's hard-coded and not user configurable. No, I do not know why. It seems like it should actually have the ability to do that, but it doesn't. On the positive side, there are all sorts of easy ways to move the file after you've created it. You can even alias it, if you want.

Comment: I had asked a similar question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254107/change-the-default-location-of-inbuilt-screen-recorder. And pomsky said that it is hardcoded and hence not possible to change it

Comment: Ahhh darn, well, thank you two for letting me know!

Comment: @user8243 On the plus side, it's open source. You could probably change where it saves by looking for the $HOME/Video variable (or similar) and then just recompile it with your own custom location. I'd not even begin to know exactly where to start, but it's probably on GitHub. You could also do a feature request. It makes sense that you should be able to change the default save location. It seems strange that you can't. You could also try different screencasting software. `apt-cache search screencast` shows some choices already in the repositories and a search says there are more options.

Comment: Wouldn't manually mounting the USB drive to ~/Videos do the trick?